# different path syntax in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, path

question , some time we use ./ and some time ../

what is the difference

**1st case**

```
let arr = require("../country/state/city/index");


let getFiNa = require("../utilities/utils/index");


let getPeopleInCity = (arr) => {
  return getFiNa(arr);
};


console.log(getPeopleInCity(arr));


module.exports = getPeopleInCity;
```

**2nd case**

```
const ob = require("./exportObject");
```

i am confused between these two syntax ./ amd ../ although i know the meaning in terminal but in JS module cases i am confused , help me to understand

Comment: `.` is the current directory, `..` is the parent directory. This is not specific to node.js, it's just normal Unix and Windows pathname syntax.

Answer (score 3):

`.` Means in that folder choose the file
`../` means go exit the current dir/folder and select from that previous or parent dir

Take reference from the image given below
`./` means on the same node
`../` means go on the previous node
[image]